# Unable to enable Wifi/Bluetooth

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, htc-one-x, connectify

I have a HTC One X , Android 4.2.2, everything worked as a charm, but suddenly my WIFI/Bluetooth functionality stopped working. I cant see any WIFI network and cant turn WIFI on/off.

It just shows me the message: 'Error' on the Settings > Wifi dashboard. also I cant enable bluetooth.

At Settings > Info > Hardware info it states:

Wifi: 802.11 a/b/g/n
Wifi MAC Adres: Unavailable.
Bluetooth: 4.0
Bluetooth adres: Unavailable.

I tried a wifi diagnostic app (Wifi fixer) it states: WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN

I tried the following:

- give it a static IP-adres, but I can't reach the advanced settings tab. (Settings > Wifi > Advanced)
- Soft and Factory Reset.

Because it cant tell me the MAC adres of the wificard/Bluetooth is unavailable. I am afraid that the radio unit is broken.

Do you have some suggestions for a fix or how to trace the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any custom ROMs on the device, is it rooted at all?

Comment: No customizations whatsoever. It is the original OS

Answer (score 0):

Like you said - it may be a problem with the H/W itself because if its a S/W problem it should've been rectified after **hard reset** (in most of the cases). If the device is on warranty I'd suggest taking it to a service centre ASAP :)

Comment: Hard reset or new rom installation does not change values in /persist/ partition, so if the problem is there as seems to be, hard reset will have no impact at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hardware problem, was caused on many devices since Android Lolipop updates, was worst with Marshmallow updates (Mine Nexux 6 was broken at that point) and now Android N beta doesn't fix anything, seems to be related to the new way system validates and provide macaddress informations, seems that in some cases it simply broke, there are reports on many forums like
http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help/wifi-mac-address-200000000000-t3257465/page4
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/-yq035tmhB8
Sadly Google simply is denying the fact that they are broking devices.

When my wifi/bluetooth stops to respond I've was on unrooted, stock rom google/motorola denied support, now I've rooted it and triying to fix it, but this is happening with many, many devices.